# Как в Python реализовать проверку на int всего списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:

> Написать функцию которая принимает на вход список, если в списке все
>   объекты - int, сортирует его. Иначе выбрасывает ValueError.

Я написал такую функцию, но она выбрасывает ValueError только если текст самый первый в списке ,а если он будет в конце программа выбросит ошибку о том ,что она не может отсортировать список с текстом. Мне надо дописать функцию так ,чтобы она выбрасывала ошибку ValueError если в списке есть строка, независимо от того в начале, конце или середине находится эта строка. Моя функция:

```
def check(x):
    for i in x:
        p = isinstance(i, int)
        if p == True:
            print(sorted(x))
        else:
            try:
                raise ValueError("Value Error")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)


check(["test", 12,56])
```

Answer (score 4):

Исправленный алгоритм из вопроса:

```
def check(x):
    for i in x:
        if not isinstance(i, int):
            raise ValueError("Value Error")

    print(sorted(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть 2 способа, явно проверить все значения на принадлежность к типу `int`, такой подход называют [LBYL (Look before you leap)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-lbyl), или использовать подход [EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp), первый случай уже описан в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/839334/236727), второй же может выглядеть так:

```
def check(arr):
    try:
        return sorted(arr)
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError('Value Error')
```

Сравнение LBYL & EAFP можно [найти тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/).

Answer (score 2):

```
def check(x):
    if not all(map(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), x)):
        raise ValueError("Value Error")

    print(sorted(x))
```

Только это не идиоматично. Как Лутц в "Изучаем Python", так и Рамальо в "Fluent Python" утверждают, что программа не должна проверять параметры, а должна выбрасывать исключение именно в той точке, где параметр не подошёл.

Comment: `try: sum(arr) except TypeError: raise ValueError`